# @Transaction not being rolled back in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jdbc, transactions

I have class based config so for roll back transaction.I have used jdbcTemplate.My bean declaration are as follows:

```
    @Bean
    public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.5:1521:DCGCDB");
        dataSource.setUsername("PCA_OWNER");
        dataSource.setPassword("PCA_OWNER");

        return dataSource;
    }
<!--for transaction bean-->
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager txManager() {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
}
```

So in my Service class I have declared the @Transactional but it is not working:

```
@Service
public class ProcessAnexOneServiceImpl implements ProcessAnexOneService {

 @Autowired
 private SelectionCustomOfficeService selectionCustomOfficeService;

 @Autowired
 private LetterDocService letterDocService;

 @Autowired
 private LetterService letterService;

 @Override
 @Transactional
 public void insertProcessAnexOne(ProcessAnexOne processAnexOne, String entryBy) {

  BigDecimal zeroValue = new BigDecimal(0);

  Letter letter = new Letter(processAnexOne.getLetter().getLetterId(), processAnexOne.getLetter().getInout(),
   processAnexOne.getLetter().getInoutNo());
 letter.setEntryBy(entryBy);

  //1st insert Transaction happens here
  BigDecimal letterNo = letterService.insertLetter(letter);
  //1st insert Transaction ends here
  System.out.println("letterNo from db is" + letterNo);


    //2nd insert Transaction happens here 
  for (BigDecimal docId: processAnexOne.getDocId()) {
   LetterDoc letterDoc = new LetterDoc(letterNo, singledocId, null, null);

   letterDocService.insertLetterDoc(letterDoc, entryBy);


  }
 //2nd insert Transaction ends here 

   //3rd insert Transaction happens here 
  for (LetterDocOther letterDoc: processAnexOne.getLetterDocOthers()) {
   System.out.println("entered hereasfdsafsdsdfg");
   LetterDoc letterD = new LetterDoc(letterNo, letterDoc.getDocId(), null, "I",
    letterDoc.getOthersDescription());
   letterD.setEntryBy(entryBy);
   letterDocService.insertLetterDocWithDescription(letterD);
  }
 //3rd insert Transaction ends here 
 }

}
```

I have three transactions which will hit on three different table in this service class.So my problem is that when the 1st transaction is done and there is error in 2nd transaction,then there is no any roll back happening in 1st transaction.At that condition,I still see the data of 1st transaction in my table but error is coming in 2nd transaction. I have declared @Transaction annotation for rollback and also tried (rollbackOn=Exception.class) but it is not rollbacking the first transaction if there is error.

In my pom.xml I have added:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

LetterServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class LetterServiceImpl implements LetterService {

    @Autowired
    private LetterDao letterDao;

    @Override
    @Transactional(rollbackOn=Exception.class)
    public BigDecimal insertLetter(Letter letter) {
        BigDecimal letter1=letterDao.saveLetter(letter);
        return letter1;
    }
}
```

LetterDaoImpl.java

```
@Override
    public BigDecimal saveLetter(Letter letter) {
        try {
        System.out.println("hitted123 here");
        SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withProcedureName("PCPR_ADD_LETTER");
        Map<String, Object> inParamMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        System.out.println(letter.getLetterId());
        inParamMap.put("P_LETTER_NO",null);
        inParamMap.put("P_LETTER_ID",letter.getLetterId());
        inParamMap.put("P_SIGNATARY",letter.getSignatary());
        inParamMap.put("P_LETTER_BOX",letter.getLetterBox());
        inParamMap.put("P_ENTRY_BY",letter.getEntryBy());
        inParamMap.put("P_R_STATUS","I");
        inParamMap.put("P_REMINDER_YES_NO","N");

        System.out.println("hitted1234 here");
        SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource(inParamMap);
        System.out.println("hitted123456789 here");
        //Map<String, Object> out = simpleJdbcCall.execute(in);
        BigDecimal letterNO =  (BigDecimal) simpleJdbcCall.execute(in).get("P_LETTER_NO");

        System.out.println("hitted12345 here"+letterNO);
        return letterNO;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }
```

Comment: Show how `insertLetter` is defined

Comment: the method of insertLetter is working fine which returns me a BigDecimal (number) value and is used by other methods.

Comment: Does it have `@Transactional` annotation on it and it methods?

Comment: No wait i will edit the post and see it

Comment: ok see i have added the codes

Comment: Transaction will be rolled back on exception. Your problem is you catch the exception. You need to rethrow it.

Comment: If you have 3 separate transactions you will not be able to rollback. You have to do everything in a single transaction. Next to that you are also catching the exception, which breaks proper rollback semantics. Finally if you are using MySQL as a database make sure you are using InnoDB tables and not MyISAM tables.

Comment: 3 transactions means 3 tables will be hitted while saving it and when letter is saved the letterNo is returned succesffuly but whnen there is error in while inserting in 2nd table the data in first table is not rolled back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Spring Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-rolling-back), Rollback is done automatically for unhandled exceptions. In this case, you are handling it so the transaction manager won't see there was an error.

On the other hand, Rollback will happen with any kind of unchecked exception(the ones extending RuntimeException) withouth need to declare them in the @Transactional annotation. However, checked annotation (the ones that you need to handle in catch blocks) needs to be declare in the @Transactional annotation.

Finally I would suggest you to add the rollback in the highest level method, that is, the one that starts the transacction, to ensure the transactional behavior.

Comment: what should i remove or make changes to make it correc? should i remove try catch block at saveLetter()?

Comment: yes, keep in mind that normally hibernate converts the exceptions into unchecked, so the code is cleaner and portable. So probably all the exceptions you will have are  unchecked and should be caught by @Transactional.

Comment: furthermore, try to avoid catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();} if you don't know how to handle the exception in the method, rethrow the exception

Comment: i am not using hibernate sir i am using jdbcTemplate

Comment: oh... ok, then the exception you may have will be checked, you will need to add them to the @Transactional annotation

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on LetterDaoImpl.java, you are catching any exception in the method saveLetter. If you catch the exception and you don't throw it back, you don't get the rollback.

Also, you should check the annotation @Transactional because I'm pretty sure the syntax is rollbackFor() instead of rollbackOn().

For debug purposes with transactions, I usually enable the log at DEBUG level for org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.

Comment: what should i do to make it correct? can u help me?

Comment: I don't like to catch the exceptions inside DAOs, but if you want to, you can throw a new exception after logging the error: throw new RuntimeException(e);